# Where should i put a command file on OSX to make it available on everywhere

Tags: macos

I'm trying to write [Cortex Amiga floppy emulator](https://cortexamigafloppydrive.wordpress.com) firmware to Gotek floppy emulator. I have downloaded a command line flash loader utility named cortexflash from [this web page](http://www.vexforum.com/showthread.php?t=73807).

I want this file to be availabe in 'path'. Where should i copy it? In applications folder? In /bin  folder? Or somewhere else?

Edit: When I check `$path` with `echo $path` I get:

```
/usr/bin          /bin       /opt/X11/bin
/usr/sbin         /sbin      /usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

So I'm going with `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: so look at what $path is and put your stuff in one of those directories. hopefully there's /usr/local/bin, which is where you'd typically put "local" installs like that.

Answer (score 1):

When adding command-line tools, the usual standard is `/usr/local/bin/`. Most of the others you're seeing are used for standard system commands of various types. Anything in `/opt/` is an add-on, but you can't count on people having that in `$PATH` unless you're including an installer that modifies their account setup.